# Package not installing correctly to Python environment

Tags: python, anaconda

I am trying to install PyJWT package into an environment, but running into an issue where it seems to have installed, and I can import the package in python, but the package is empty.

I do the following from a Windows command line:

```
activate my-env
```

and I see my command prompt reflect the change by showing (my-env)
then I issue

```
pip -install PyJwt
```

and that says successful. So now I run python and try

```
import jwt
dir(jwt)
```

The import works, but `dir()` gives the following output:

```
['__doc__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__']
```

HOWEVER, if I do not first select the environment, i.e. I do a `pip install` without first activating an environment, then the install works correctly and when I run `dir` on the package I see the right output:

```
['DecodeError', 'ExpiredSignature', 'ExpiredSignatureError', 'ImmatureSignatureError', 'InvalidAlgorithmError', 'InvalidAudience', 'InvalidAudienceError', 'InvalidIssuedAtError', 'InvalidIssuer', 'InvalidIssuerError', 'InvalidSignatureError', 'InvalidTokenError', 'MissingRequiredClaimError', 'PyJWS', 'PyJWT', 'PyJWTError', '__author__', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__copyright__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__license__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', '__title__', '__version__', 'algorithms', 'api_jws', 'api_jwt', 'compat', 'decode', 'encode', 'exceptions', 'get_unverified_header', 'register_algorithm', 'unregister_algorithm', 'utils']
```

The issue of course is the package now isn't available in the environment in which I want to use it.

Any suggestions on what I've done to create this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you actually try to use the package and got an error, or are you just looking at the output of `dir(...)` and *think* that something's wrong? Maybe the Python version in your conda environment uses lazy loading, while the Python version outside of conda does not.

Since you're using Anaconda, consider to install [PyJWT with `conda`](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/pyjwt) instead of `pip` into your environment. This should resolve all dependencies automatically:

```
conda activate my-env
conda install pyjwt
```

Comment: It's definitely broken, I can't call any of the methods (e.g. decode) that should be in the package. The dir() is just a useful diagnostic. However, your suggestion of conda has worked, so thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Before installation you need to remove the package by using the below command:

```
apt-get remove python3-jwt
```

In this case, the installer will install the package using the below command:

```
pip3 install pyjwt
```